# Loop JSON String response in PHP Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to print values of a JSON response in PHP. Inside the contents are:

```
data
local
acao
detalhes
```

Codes:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$url = "http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/correios/rastreamento/json/RJ290474594CN";
$c_url = file_get_contents($url); 
$c_url = utf8_encode($c_url); 
$results = json_decode($c_url); 

echo $c_url;
?>
```

I've tried using `foreach` but wasn't successful in implementing them in said JSON response.

Here is a JSON String Example:

```
[{"data":"07\/12\/2014 11:19","local":"CHINA - CHINA\/CN","acao":"postado","detalhes":"-"},{"data":"09\/12\/2014 12:03","local":"CHINA - CHINA\/CN","acao":"encaminhado","detalhes":"Em tr\u00e2nsito para Unidade de Tratamento Internacional - BRASIL\/BR"},{"data":"29\/12\/2014 12:34","local":"UNIDADE TRAT INTERNACIONAL PARANA - Curitiba\/PR","acao":"conferido","detalhes":"Recebido\/Brasil "}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print values just print them accordingly using foreach. After getting the response, use `json_decode()`. That `ut8f_encode()` is superfluous.

```
$url = "http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/correios/rastreamento/json/RJ290474594CN";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 
foreach($data as $values) {
    echo $values['data'] . '<br/>';
    echo $values['local'] . '<br/>';
    echo $values['acao'] . '<br/>';
    echo $values['detalhes'] . '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4KYHrG)

Or:

```
$url = "http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/correios/rastreamento/json/RJ290474594CN";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 
foreach($data as $values) {
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        echo "{$key}: $value <br/>";
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```